# ¿Por que mi string que contiene HTML no se imprime en la pantalla?

Tags: javascript, html, html5, string

En mi código estoy intentando poner un string que contiene HTML dentro pero al parecer no lo agarra. Ni en un `for` ni en un `textNode`. *¿Alguien me puede decir cómo puedo corregirlo?* El string se imprime tal cual sin modificar nada.

Aquí esta el HTML que quiero imprimir:

```
function createListElement() {
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    li.classList.add("list");
    li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(input.value + "<button>Eliminar</button>"));
    ul.appendChild(li);
    input.value = "";
    eventoSubrayar();
}
```

Aquí todo mi código de JS por cualquier cosa:

```
var button = document.getElementById("enter");
var input = document.getElementById("userinput");
var ul = document.querySelector("ul");
var liAll = document.querySelectorAll("li");

function inputLength (){
    return input.value.length;
}

function createListElement() {
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    li.classList.add("list");
    li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(input.value + "<button>Eliminar</button>"));
    ul.appendChild(li);
    input.value = "";
    eventoSubrayar();
}

function AddListAfterClick() {
    if (inputLength() > 0) {
        createListElement();
    }
}

function AddListAfterEnter(event) {
    if (inputLength() > 0 && event.keyCode === 13) {
        createListElement();
    }
}

function AddClassList() {
    for(let i = 0; i < liAll.length; i++) {
        liAll[i].className += "list"; 
    }
}

function EndTaskList() {
    this.classList.toggle("done")
}



button.addEventListener("click", AddListAfterClick);

input.addEventListener("keypress", AddListAfterEnter);

function eventoSubrayar() {
    for(var i = 0; i < document.querySelectorAll(".list").length; i++) {
        document.querySelectorAll(".list")[i].addEventListener("click", EndTaskList)
    };
}

function botonEliminar() {
    for (var i = 0; i < document.querySelectorAll(".list").length; i++) {
        var a = document.querySelectorAll(".list");
        a[i] = a[i] + "hi";
    }
}

AddClassList();
eventoSubrayar();
```

Gracias...

Comment: [createTextNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/createTextNode) es para texto, no para HTML, en todo caso, asigna el contenido con `li.innerHTML = 'valor y botón';`

Answer (score 0):

Si lo que quieres es que se imprima un botón al momento que das click en enter tienes que crear también el elemento `button` de la siguiente manera:

```html
function createListElement() {
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    var liButton = document.createElement("Button");
    liButton.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Eliminar"));
    li.classList.add("list");
    li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(input.value + " "));
    li.appendChild(liButton);
    ul.appendChild(li);
    input.value = "";
    eventoSubrayar();
}
```

Inténtalo y me cuentas si se soluciono tu problema.